# anbox-cloud performance issue Edit

Tags: performance

- Server : Dell PowerEdge R740 (48 cores ) (with hyperthreading enabled 96 vcpu cores) (RAM: 384 GB)
- GPU : NVIDIA A16 4 cards
- OS : Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (x86_64)
- Anbox-cloud-appliance version : 1.19.2

I am evaluating anbox-cloud for cloud gaming on the above mentioned server (single node baremetal server).

I have created anbox application with a game apk (subway_surfers) using the dashboard.

I have also created another anbox application with a test apk (which plays the recorded game video session as soon as it is launched) for creating loadtest sessions.

Using the following bash script to launch the loadtest sessions:

```
#!/bin/bash
# For loop with number range
for i in {0..60}
do
anbox-cloud-tests.benchmark -t 30 --insecure-tls --screen-width=1280 --screen-height=720 --screen-fps=60 --application=testanbox --url=https://172.19.119.176 --auth-token="AgEUYW5ib3gtc3RyZWFtLWdhdGV3YXkCBHRlc3QAAhQyMDIzLTExLTExVDAxOjExOjI3WgACFDIwMjQtMTEtMTBUMDE6MTE6MjdaAAAGIDHbdvRYiCZtSD95wWYm7OhgOVb4iUR-yar8skQc-yNu" &
sleep 10
done
```

Once the loadtest sessions are active, from dashboard I am creating a session for the game application (subway_surfers) and checking the play experience.

Under load it is observed that there are occasional fps drops.

I have also attached some screenshots captured under load.

What is the reason for fps drops affecting gameplay experience even when cpu usage (50%) has not peaked and GPU usage (40%) has not peaked?

Are there any recommended nvidia settings to avoid fps drop under load?
Are there any anbox cloud specific settings to avoid fps drop under load?

With the above mentioned server and GPU cards, what is the number of maximum concurrent sessions that could be run with 720p and 60fps cloud gaming sessions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The anbox-cloud-tests.benchmark report shows fps dropping from 30fps

|                    Video |                  Average |                      Min |                      Max |                   Stddev |
Count |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Bandwidth (Mbit/s)  |                     2.29 |                     1.07 |                     2.47 |                     0.29 |                       89 |
|          Frames received |                    29.63 |                    22.80 |                    29.95 |                     1.12 |                       89 |
|           Frames decoded |                    29.62 |                    22.80 |                    29.95 |                     1.15 |                       89 |
|           Frames dropped |                     0.01 |                     0.00 |                     0.55 |                     0.08 |                       89 |
|             Freeze count |                     0.01 |                     0.00 |                     0.15 |                     0.03 |                       89 |
|              Pause count |                     0.00 |                     0.00 |                     0.00 |                     0.00 |                       89 |
|       Key frames decoded |                     0.00 |                     0.00 |                     0.10 |                     0.01 |                       89 |
| Frame assembly time (ms) |                     0.00 |                     0.00 |                     0.00 |                     0.00 |

How can the fps drop avoided under load of 60 concurrent sessions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.